# Why is my .hover() not working?

Tags: jquery, hover

I'm trying to put `#TyBio` into the box called `#descriptblock` when I hover over the image called `#TyPhoto`. I looked at several examples where people did something similar to this, but for some reason the text will not show when I hover. Thanks in advance!

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#TyPhoto").hover(function(){
    $("#TyBio").show();
},function () {
    $("#TyBio").hide();

});

});
```

CSS

```
#descriptblock {
z-index:5;
width:1150px;
height:100px;
top:270px;
left:0px;
position:absolute;
background:white;
text-align:left;
display:block;
}

    #TyBio{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B4nfVqlTfnTzQ0V5NlQydy0xU00" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
<li><img id="TyPhoto" src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B4nfVqlTfnTzWDVMRzBEd1RwX2s" width="204" height="272" /></li>
<li><img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B4nfVqlTfnTzU0pTYWVwRXZ0Tjg" width="208" height="286" /></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
<span id="descriptblock">
<div id="TyBio">TESTTHISBIOTEST!</div>
</span>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pdugK/  - what is wrong here?

Comment: It seems to be working. Which browser are you seeing the issue ?

Comment: Thanks you guys! I realized that I just forgot to add the .js file to that page. I've been working with multiple pages that use the same file and just spaced adding it to that one. Well, mystery solved. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML doesn't include either your JavaScript or the jQuery library that it depends on.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="your.js"></script>
```

If I add them, then it [works](http://jsbin.com/equgir/1/edit).

Comment: That was a good idea, but I added them, and it still isn't working. 
This is the actual URL: http://2013.igem.org/Team:Georgia_State/teamgallery.html

EDIT: I forgot to add my own JS file to that page. I've been working with other pages that were already linked and forgot to add it to the one I needed. WOW.

Comment: "I forgot to add my own JS file to that page." — That's what I said!

Comment: Haha, yes and credit to you! Sorry, was so flabbergasted at that fact that I forgot to thank you specifically. Thanks Quentin!

Answer (score 0):

You included 2 versions of jquery library files.

http://2013.igem.org/Team:Georgia_State/teamgallery.html

View source, line 71 (v1.4.2), and  line 132(v1.9.1).